# m2mqtt with TLS connection in C#

Tags: ssl, connection, mqtt

I can connect to broker with mosquitto_sub I am using Mqtt and M2Mqtt in C#

```
mosquitto_sub -h {URL} -p {PORT} -t {topic} --psk {psk} --psk-identity {psk-identity} --tls-version tlsv1
```

I have no idea how to implement it with M2Mqtt in C#.

Do I need to generate certificate file by openssl?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.

Comment: No, I gave it up and done it in Java.

Comment: No problem, I am thinking the same thing, do you have any pointers to articles / libraries / info for a java implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I said wrong. I run m2mqtt broker client side to get data from server side and create a java program to get data from m2mqtt broker client. I did not change its structure. 

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick :-)